# sfml 2.2 fps function repeating numbers

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml, frame-rate

When I try to show an fps counter in my program with this code:

```
sf::Clock clock;
sf::Time time = clock.getElapsedTime();
std::cout << 1.0f / time.asSeconds() << std::endl;
clock.restart().asSeconds();
```

It just repeats the numbers "500000" and "333333", even though I set the framerate limit to 60. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `asSeconds`? We're dealing with milliseconds. And `clock.restart()` alone restarts the clock, no `.asSeconds()` is needed after that, IIRC.

Comment: Tried that, now it just says "inf"...

Comment: Without more code it's hard to say what is wrong, but are you creating a new `Clock` on every frame and `cout`ing its elapsed time in the next statement? (What I'm saying is that the `Clock` has to persist between frames as is done in [this example](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-time.php#measuring-framerate).)

Comment: @Sean Quite possible, because of `1.0f / 0` giving `inf`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UGugKS76 here is the source

Comment: @rob Yes, make the clock global, or pass it into that function by reference (don't create it in the loop, again).

Comment: What would I do here if I already have a clock. It says I can't have 2 clocks even though they aren't the same thing. Would it be worth it just to upgrade to 2.3? (sorry i'm new to this) :)

Comment: Ah, fixed it. Thank you everyone!!